# Where can I get IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix for offline installation?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I know I can install IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix on-line from [Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-eclipse-tools-bluemix) or [WasDev site](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-IBM_Eclipse_Tools_for_Bluemix), but I am looking for a download package (ZIP file) to be able to install it in offline machines.

Thanks!

Comment: The eclipse tools for bluemix allows you to connect to the bluemix server to deploy your apps etc. Why would you want to install this on an offline machine? Did you mean to ask for the liberty server tools for eclipse?

Comment: For some workshops, we need to install and prepare some machines in advance without network connection. That is the reason I need a downloaded zip file. Later, of course, to use it there will be connection.

Comment: Ah ok this makes more sense, the way your original post was phrased implied these were permanently offline machines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the eclipse repository mirroring function to download the IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix to a local directory that you can then point your offline eclipse installs to. You can follow the guidelines for the repository mirroring [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Repository_Mirroring).

The IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix update site can be found on the [marketplace page](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-eclipse-tools-bluemix) as the update site/download symbol. The update site is [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/cloud/V1.0/).

If you follow the repository mirroring wiki then you just need to do the following:

```
eclipse -nosplash -verbose
 -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication
 -source http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/cloud/V1.0/
 -destination /tmp/eclipsetoolsforbluemix
```

then (note this can take some time as it downloads the content):

```
eclipse -nosplash -verbose
 -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication
 -source http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/cloud/V1.0/
 -destination /tmp/eclipsetoolsforbluemix
```

once these are finished you can go to your Eclipse install, choose '*Help->Install New Software..*', click on '*Add Repository*' and choose your local repository (i.e. /tmp/eclipsetoolsforbluemix). You should then be able to install the plugin from your local repository without the need for internet access, obviously the local repository could be on a usb stick or a shared drive dependent on how you want to do the installs.

For the IBM Eclipse tools for Bluemix you will need to make sure you also check the Cloud Foundry plugins to be installed, these are included in the mirror. The Liberty Server eclipse plugin is an optional install.